# How to change version of readline, from libedit to gnu?

Tags: python, python-2.7, enthought, canopy

I am trying to get [PsiTurk](https://psiturk.org/) running on my OSX 10.9.5 machine but I am having an issue with [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html)

Apparently Mac versions of Python 2.7 use the `libedit` version of readline while I need to use the gnu version of readline. The below is the error I'm getting when i try to run psiturk.

> libedit version of readline detected. readline will not be well
>   behaved, which may cause all sorts of problems for the psiTurk shell.
>   We highly recommend installing the gnu version of readline by running
>   "sudo pip install gnureadline". Note: "pip install readline" will NOT
>   work because of how the OSX pythonpath is structured.

Running `sudo pip install gnureadline` has no effect. After some investigation I found through [this Google Group question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/psiturk/hmaHyNb3dus) and [the Documentation](http://psiturk.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#installation-requirements) that Enthought Python distribution is recommended as it uses gnu readline.

> A python installation (<= v2.7). We recommend the Enthough python
>   distribution on Mac OS X.

**Question:** Is it possible to switch which version of readline I use, from `libedit readline` to `gnu readline`? And how do I do this?

My entire project was built using the native version of Python 2.7.5 on my machine and I'm not certain about changing over to Enthought

Thanks